# Optimize SQL query with 3 FOR loops

Tags: sql, postgresql, query-optimization, postgis

I have a fully working SQL query. However, it is very very slow. I am looking for a way to optimize it.

```
CREATE TABLE trajectory_geom (
  id                        SERIAL PRIMARY KEY,
  trajectory_id             BIGINT,
  user_id               BIGINT,
  geom                  GEOMETRY(Linestring, 4326)
);

INSERT INTO trajectory_geom (trajectory_id, user_id, geom)
    SELECT
        p.trajectory_id,
        p.user_id,
        ST_Transform(ST_MakeLine(p.geom), 4326)
    FROM point p
    GROUP BY p.trajectory_id
;

DO $$
DECLARE
  urow record;
  vrow record;
  wrow record;
BEGIN
  FOR wrow IN
  SELECT DISTINCT(p.user_id) FROM point p
  LOOP
    raise notice 'User id: %', wrow.user_id;
    FOR vrow IN
    SELECT DISTINCT(p.trajectory_id) FROM point p WHERE p.user_id = wrow.user_id
    LOOP
      FOR urow IN
      SELECT
        analyzed_tr.*
      FROM trajectory_start_end_geom analyzed_tr
      WHERE
      analyzed_tr.user_id = wrow.user_id
      AND
      ST_Intersects (
        (
         analyzed_tr.start_geom
        )
        ,
        (
          SELECT g.geom
          FROM trajectory_geom g
          WHERE g.trajectory_id = vrow.trajectory_id
        )
      ) = TRUE
      LOOP
        INSERT INTO trajectories_intercepting_with_starting_point (initial_trajectory_id, mathced_trajectory_id, user_id)
          SELECT
            vrow.trajectory_id,
            urow.trajectory_id,
            wrow.user_id
          WHERE urow.trajectory_id <> vrow.trajectory_id
        ;
      END LOOP;
    END LOOP;
  END LOOP;
END;
$$;
```

It has 3 loops...how can I avoid them?

Basically, I am looping all user IDs, for each user looping all trajectories and checking is trajectory interact with any other trajectory of this user.

Schema:

```
CREATE TABLE public.trajectory_start_end_geom
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trajectory_start_end_geom_id_seq'::regclass),
  trajectory_id bigint,
  user_id bigint,
  start_geom geometry(Polygon,4326),
  end_geom geometry(Polygon,4326),
  CONSTRAINT trajectory_start_end_geom_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE public.trajectory_geom
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('trajectory_geom_id_seq'::regclass),
  trajectory_id bigint,
  user_id bigint,
  geom geometry(LineString,4326),
  CONSTRAINT trajectory_geom_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);

CREATE TABLE public.point
(
  id integer NOT NULL DEFAULT nextval('point_id_seq'::regclass),
  user_id bigint,
  date date,
  "time" time without time zone,
  lat double precision,
  lon double precision,
  trajectory_id integer,
  geom geometry(Geometry,4326),
  CONSTRAINT point_pkey PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
WITH (
  OIDS=FALSE
);
```

Comment: Why not do it in a single query rather than procedure?

Comment: Actually I want a single query. Just procedure is what I managed to come up with

Comment: You don't need any loops, you can accomplish this just by joining the tables you need.

Comment: Can you add to your question simple database schema? I think you can easy solve this task with JOIN operator

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this SQL query. Hope this helps.

```
INSERT INTO trajectories_intercepting_with_starting_point 
(initial_trajectory_id, mathced_trajectory_id, user_id)
SELECT 
        TG.trajectory_id AS first_trajectory_id,
        TG2.trajectory_id AS last_trajectory_id,
        TG.user_id
FROM Trajectory_geom AS TG
    JOIN Trajectory_geom AS TG2 ON TG.user_id = TG2.user_id
                                       AND TG.trajectory_id < TG2.trajectory_id
    JOIN Trajectory_start_end_geom AS TSE ON TSE.trajectory_id = TG.trajectory_id
WHERE ST_Intersects(TSE.start_geom, TG2.geom) = TRUE
```

Comment: Why this is needed ```JOIN Trajectory_geom AS TG2 ON TG.user_id = TG2.user_id
                                       AND TG.trajectory_id < TG2.trajectory_id```?

Comment: You need to check every user trajectory_id with another to find match. So I've made temp table.

Answer (score 2):

This should do the trick:

```
WITH vrow AS(
INSERT INTO trajectory_geom (trajectory_id, user_id, geom)
    SELECT
        p.trajectory_id,
        p.user_id,
        ST_Transform(ST_MakeLine(p.geom), 4326) AS geom
    FROM point p
    GROUP BY p.trajectory_id
RETURNING trajectory_id, user_id, geom
)
INSERT INTO trajectories_intercepting_with_starting_point (initial_trajectory_id, mathced_trajectory_id, user_id)
          SELECT
            vrow.trajectory_id,
            urow.trajectory_id,
            vrow.user_id
          FROM trajectory_start_end_geom AS urow          
        JOIN vrow 
            ON urow.user_id = vrow.user_id 
            AND urow.trajectory_id <> vrow.trajectory_id
            AND ST_Intersects(urow.start_geom, vrow.geom)
```

If you don't need insert into `trajectory_geom` eliminating it (and the CTE) will speed it up

Comment: I am not familiar with RETURNING  syntax and getting an error: `ERROR:  missing FROM-clause entry for table "p"
LINE 9: RETURNING p.trajectory_id, p.user_id, geom`.

Comment: Ohh, just to remove `p`.